# Multiply arrays along a given axis

Tags: python, numpy, array-broadcasting

I'm currently multiplying two arrays with different dimensions as follows

```
x = np.ones((100, 10, 10))
y = np.arange(0, 100)

for i in range(x.shape[1]):
    for j in range(x.shape[2]):
        x[:, i, j] *= y
```

I've been thinking about how I can rewrite this without using nested for loops but haven't had any good ideas. Is there a way to do this natively with numpy arrays, or at least without the nested loops?

Comment: `x * y[:,None,None]`?

Comment: I didn't know you could index numpy arrays like that. That's awesome!